# Generate a weekly calendar based upon Week Start and Week End dates

Tags: function, calendar, sql-server-2017, dayofweek

I'm trying to create a script that would give me the fiscal weeks based upon reference dates of Start Week and End Week

For example, assume that I have table columns with StartWeek and EndWeek such that:

```
StartWeek | EndWeek
----------|---------
20190603  | 20190609
20190610  | 20190616
20190617  | 20190623
20190624  | 20190630
20190701  | 20190707
...
```

I would like a script to generate the following:

```
FiscalDateStart | FiscalDateEnd  |  NumOfDays | WeekDayStart | WeekDayEnd
----------------|----------------|------------|--------------|-----------
2019-06-05      | 2019-06-09     |  5         | Wednesday    | Sunday
2019-06-10      | 2019-06-16     |  7         | Monday       | Sunday
2019-06-17      | 2019-06-23     |  7         | Monday       | Sunday
2019-06-24      | 2019-06-30     |  7         | Monday       | Sunday
2019-07-01      | 2019-07-02     |  2         | Monday       | Tuesday
```

I have found the following logic on Stack:

```
DECLARE   @StartDate DATE = '2019-06-05'
        , @EndDate DATE = '2019-07-02'

SET DATEFIRST 1
SET LANGUAGE French;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select *
    from
(Select 
       WeekNum   = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By FY,FM Order By FW)
      ,StartDate = Min(D) over (Partition By FY,FM,FW )
      ,EndDate   = Max(D) over (Partition By FY,FM,FW )
      ,NumOfDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, Min(D) over (Partition By FY,FM,FW ), Max(D) over (Partition By FY,FM,FW )) + 1
 From 
      (
         /* Establish calendar rules/functions for Fiscal Year (FY), Fiscal Month (FM), Fiscal Week (FW), & Fiscal Day (D) */
        Select FY = DatePart(Year,@StartDate)-1+sum(case when convert(varchar(5),@StartDate,101)=convert(varchar(5),D,101) then 1 else 0 end) over (Order By D)
              ,FM = sum(case when DatePart(Day,D)=DatePart(Day,@StartDate) then 1 else 0 end) over (Order By D)
              ,FW = sum(case when DatePart(WeekDay,D)=1 then 1 else 0 end) over (Order By D)
              ,D
         From (
                /* Generate Fiscal Day (D) rule based on @StartDate & @EndDate  */
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1) 
                       D  = DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@StartDate) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
              ) A1
      ) A

  --Order By D
 ) a
 group by 
 WeekNum, StartDate, EndDate, NumOfDays
```

The issue is that we're forcing the @StartDate in the above query to be as of 2019-06-05.  However, I need the above script to generate the same results, but based upon the @StartDate as of 2019-06-03.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the first and the last rows of expected results? The first version of your question (with `StartWeek = 20190605` and `EndWeek = 20190702`) made sense, but the current version, in my opinion, is not clear.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. The fiscal week has to start on a Wednesday (i.e., 2019-06-05) given the fact that a standard week starts on the Monday (2019-06-03).  Is this more clear?

Comment: I've updated my question by adding a script I've found elsewhere on Stack by @John Cappelletti.